# Trying to re-open a closed dialog doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

When I open a dialog box and close it in my page and try to reopen it by clicking an button it doesn't open again. What's wrong with my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
$(function() {
    $(".dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode",

    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function pass_url(url) {
    $(".opener").click(function () {
      $(".dialog").dialog("open");

      $('.dialog').load(url);
      return false;

    });
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, so that others can read it, and provide some information about your problem.

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to cause any issues. Can you post an example, perhaps a jsFiddle?

Comment: why would you start a new thread without a demo when a few hours ago you asked same thing and suggestion was "create demo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you're replacing your dialog contents with the contents of `url`.

```
$(".dialog").dialog("open");
$('.dialog').load(url);
```

Why not fill a child element of `.dialog` instead?

```
$(".dialog").dialog("open");
$('.dialog .content').load(url);
```

Comment: The first code snippet replaces the **content of** `.dialog` with the contents of `url`, doesn't replace the element itself.

Comment: @jrummell actully i m opening an HTML page into the dialog box but after closing it it does not opening..and passing the url in the href by using '   javascript:var url='abc.html' '

Comment: Is it a full html page with `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` tags, etc? If so, that will cause you all kinds of problems since your containing page also has those tags.

Comment: @jrummell yehhh, it is ,,i m a beginner in this field,,,, why i cant open more then one dialog box in a page?? can give an example in which more then one dialog boxes can be opened...

Comment: Basically, what you need to do to keep valid html with your dialog, is to load a "partial page" that only includes valid body elements (e.g. a `<div>` tag with your dialog html). Or you can use the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) page fragments selector, with tells jquery to only load a specific part of the remote url (e.g. `$('.dialog .content').load(url + " #dialog");`).

Answer (score 0):

It may be that rather than closing it you're destroying it - you can't open it once it's destroyed.  Try creating fresh each time, perhaps?  (....of course, at that point you need to make *sure* that you're destroying rather than merely closing).